# Updating access token (global variable) inside a function/loop problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, spotipy

I'm extracting data using Spotify API wrapper. The access token (which is global variable) is valid for only 1 hour so I need to update it during the for loop in some defined function. I tried to update it using try/except, but I got the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spotify' referenced before assignment.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
token = credentials.get_access_token()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth = token)
...

def main():
    ...
    df_af = generate_audio_features_df(track_ids)
    ...

def generate_audio_features_df(track_ids):
    col_list = ['id', 'danceability']
    result = []
    count = 0

    for j in track_ids:
        try:
            r = spotify.audio_features(j)[0]
            features_list = [r['id'], r['danceability']]
            result.append(features_list)
            #display progress
            count += 1
            print("Added ", count, " track")
        except spotipy.client.SpotifyException:
            token = credentials.get_access_token()
            spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth = token)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data = result, columns = col_list)
    return df

if __name__ == "__init__":
    main()
```

I would like the code to update a token and get back to the loop.

Comment: add `global spotify` to the beginning of the function. Also, you have a typo in `except` - you wrote `spotipy`, instead of `spotify`

Comment: Use `global`. There's no typo, @h4z3, since he's using this lib: https://pypi.org/project/spotipy/

Comment: Thank you. Adding global helped. I'm not sure why python treated that as local variable

Comment: You can't assign to a global variable without `global`. So if you have an assignment, python treats the variable in that whole scope as local. And by "whole scope" it means that even reading from that variable before that assignment wants the local version, hence the error.